# error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Theron::EndPoint’

Tags: c++

I use Theron in my project as a actor library, when I test Theron by using "hello world" project, I met below errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Theron/Framework.h"
#include "Theron/Actor.h"
#include "Theron/Receiver.h"
#include "Theron/EndPoint.h"

using namespace std;

class Actor : public Theron::Actor
{
public:

    explicit Actor(Theron::Framework &framework) : Theron::Actor(framework)
    {
        RegisterHandler(this, &Actor::Handler);
    }

private:

    void Handler(const int &message, const Theron::Address from)
    {
        Send(message, from);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Theron::Receiver receiver;
    Theron::Framework framework;
    Actor actor(framework);

    framework.Send(int(0), receiver.GetAddress(), actor.GetAddress());

    receiver.Wait();

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -ITheron/Include/ -ITheron/Include/External/
-c /home/eliteyang/dev/test/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o In file included from /home/eliteyang/dev/test/main.cpp:2:0: Theron/Include/Theron/Framework.h: In member function ‘bool Theron::Framework::SendInternal(Theron::Detail::MailboxContext*, Theron::Detail::IMessage*, Theron::Address)’: Theron/Include/Theron/Framework.h:999:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Theron::EndPoint’
         if (!mEndPoint->Lookup(name, address.mIndex))
                       ^ In file included from Theron/Include/Theron/Framework.h:14:0,
                 from /home/eliteyang/dev/test/main.cpp:2: Theron/Include/Theron/Address.h:23:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class Theron::EndPoint’  class EndPoint;
       ^ In file included from /home/eliteyang/dev/test/main.cpp:2:0: Theron/Include/Theron/Framework.h:1002:29: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Theron::EndPoint’
             return mEndPoint->RequestSend(message, name);
                             ^ In file included from Theron/Include/Theron/Framework.h:14:0,
                 from /home/eliteyang/dev/test/main.cpp:2: Theron/Include/Theron/Address.h:23:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class Theron::EndPoint’  class EndPoint;
           ^
```

---

My environment is Ubuntu 15.04, codeblocks 13.12, gcc 4.9.1.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's compiling error, not link error

Comment: It would help if you could post your code also. On a first look, the error suggests you're missing an include statement for the header of the class Theron::EndPoint.

Comment: Add all code. Please read [Theron start](http://www.theron-library.com/index.php?t=page&p=getting%20started)

Comment: The examples there just include `<Theron/Theron.h>`, but you're including four interdependent headers, apparently in the wrong order. Is there a reason you didn't use the include line shown? Does that fix it?

Comment: I fixed it, I should include <Theron/Theron.h>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your include statements are wrong, or in the wrong order.
Apparently `Theron/Framework.h` contains some code that needs the full definition of class `EndPoint` but doesn't explicitly include the header `EndPoint.h` and instead only provides a forward declaration.

To fix this, you can either try to include `EndPoint.h` before including `Framework.h` or replace all your Theron includes with the `Theron/Theron.h` all-inclusive wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I include Theron.h directly, no more errors.